# CSV Connector For Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I've been tasked with creating a basic ETL application. We have a remote location where csv files are dropped to every month, they are approx. 250MBs in size.

The application will import the csv --> apply business logic (if required) --> insert into a SQLServer table.

I've been looking at using Kafka for this. Though, I'm fairly new to it and am unable to find a connector that will read in a import a csv file into Kafka. I've seen a few projects in github but they seem to be dated and I'm getting errors accross the board for UnsupportedOperationExceptions

Can anyone please point be in the right direction? I'm now thinking of writing a connector using confluent_kafka

Comment: The spooldir connector on Github is the one generally recommended (and written by a Confluent employee)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use Kafka (and it's not clear from your requirements that you necessarily need to) then the [kafka-connect-spooldir](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) is a good connector for your requirement. [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/) shows setup and example of it in use.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and I wrote the article :)*

Comment: Hi Robin, really appreciate  it. The article is exactly what I've been looking for. Regarding requirements, Kafka has become quite the hype these days and our organization actually has confluent enterprise. That said, my first approach was going to be spring batch but decided that kafka may be fun to try out

Comment: If you're using Apache Kafka elsewhere in the org, then it makes perfect sense to use it here too, the point being the system you're building can access data from others, and visa versa.

Comment: Hi Robin, (hopefully) one last question, the csv files I have do not have headers. is there anyway to accommodate for this? I tried using the dynamic schema generation and it did not work

Comment: One option would be to manually add the headers once, generate the schema as shown in that article, and then you can process subsequent files automatically assuming that they adhere to the same schema.

Comment:  glad it worked. Don't forget to mark the question as answered if it is :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Is there anyway to use the filename as the key?